# ValueError at /users/register/ The view users.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am getting this error ValueError at /users/register/ The view users.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I am using Django to complete the registration form, however I was unable to eliminate this problem.

```
def register(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if user_form.is_valid():
                  new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                  new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
                  new_user.save()
                  return render(request,'users/register_done.html')
            else:
                  user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
            return render(request,'users/register.html',{'user_form':user_form})
```

This is my views.py file made a register function with the return render.

`path('register/',views.register,name='register'),`

this is urls py

Is there any other solution to come over
[My result Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hetiE.png)

I am expecting the solution for my problem

Comment: It returns None if the request.method is not 'POST'

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST':` because of this you are getting error

Comment: Then, what would we do? I must make the data from the form available. and I have the provided POST method. Is there any method to correct the error.

Comment: devp What I need to do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to display error messages like if *user already exits* or *password is empty or too-small*.

Now the `return` statement is outside of `if` statement.

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
                new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
                new_user.save()
                return render(request,'users/register_done.html')
        else:
                user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'user_form':user_form})
```